# How to create global file for all projects in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the file Pathes.cs(in the screenshot);

The file is not in any project. The other projects does not see it. My task is to do that file visible for all projects. 
I tryed to use `using Homework`, to use `Homework.Pathes.pathToDataDirectory` in my projects.
But nothing helps.[image: The screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Create a Class Library project, put the file in there and reference that project in all other projects that need that class. Right-click on `Dependencies` in the Solution Explorer, go to `Projects` and select the shared class library project. This is the preferred option.
2. Link the file to the projects that need the file. Right-click on the project, click `Add > Existing Item` and navigate to the file. Instead of clicking the `Add` button, click on the arrow next to it and select `Add As Link`.
3. Copy-paste the file into the projects. This is a total maintenance nightmare, so don't go there.