# Add cs library to visual studio globally

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have to build a solution that uses the Microsoft.Enterprice library. I installed the library, [but VS still can't find the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSc1O.jpg). I have no way of making changes to the solution (it's pretty darn big). It is possible to add the library globally for VS? Тhanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create global file for all projects in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57769087/how-to-create-global-file-for-all-projects-in-visual-studio)

Comment: What do you mean by "VS still can't find the library." Can you describe what you are seeing? Are you getting compilation errors? Do you see error icons in Solution Explorer? Please be specific.

Comment: I get about 150 messages like this AccumMessageBox\Implementation\ErrorMessage.cs(1,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Practices' does not e
xist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\correct\tick\src\gui\xxx\xxx\xxx.csproj]

I build my solution using command line make command. I install the library, add path of library to the enviroment variable %PATH%, but the problem still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Microsoft doc [Enterprise Library 6 – April 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn169621(v=pandp.10)), you could try to  search for “enterpriselibrary” in the nuget-package.

For example, you could choose `EnterpriseLibrary.Data` and install it.

Then, you could use it like the following:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectionString connstr = new ConnectionString("","","");            

        }
```

You could find the correspond class library from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn170426(v=pandp.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Update from comment:
If you want to install the dll globally for visual studio. You could refer to the link [How to: Install an assembly into the global assembly cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac). Then you could use the assembly from GAC for every project without using it in the nuget-package.

Comment: As far as I know, I can install nuget packages only for individual projects or solutions. Right? Or is there a way to install them globally for visual studio?

Comment: @Arthur Tsaturyan, If you want to install the dll globally for visual studio. You could refer to the link [How to: Install an assembly into the global assembly cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac). Then you could use the assembly from GAC for every project without using it in the nuget-package.

Comment: This is the solution. Thank you!